# compiling and cpu architecture error for apple despite being on an ubuntu?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to compile something from a github branch. I'm on an ubuntu.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
```

with the following configuration.

```
❯ rustup -V
rustup 1.24.3 (ce5817a94 2021-05-31)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.61.0-nightly (d53246fed 2022-03-25)`

❯ cargo -V                                                               
cargo 1.61.0-nightly (109bfbd 2022-03-17)


❯ rustup default                                                         
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
```

however when trying to compile I get this error.

```
error: no rules expected the token `aarch64_apple`
   --> /home/ahdee/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/src/cpu.rs:257:13
    |
165 |     macro_rules! features {
    |     --------------------- when calling this macro
...
257 |             aarch64_apple: true,
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no rules expected this token in macro call

error[E0425]: cannot find value `AES` in module `cpu::arm`
   --> /home/ahdee/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/src/aead/aes.rs:381:65
    |
381 |         if cpu::intel::AES.available(cpu_features) || cpu::arm::AES.available(cpu_features) {
    |                                                                 ^^^ not found in `cpu::arm`
    |
help: consider importing this constant
    |
15  | use crate::cpu::intel::AES;
    |

error[E0425]: cannot find value `PMULL` in module `cpu::arm`
   --> /home/ahdee/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/src/aead/gcm.rs:315:26
    |
315 |             || cpu::arm::PMULL.available(cpu_features)
    |                          ^^^^^ not found in `cpu::arm`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `ARMCAP_STATIC` in this scope
   --> /home/ahdee/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/src/cpu.rs:235:41
    |
```

Comment: Looks to be an error with the latest nightly: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/95267

Comment: @kmdreko perfect, thanks. I forced an earlier build and it worked out fine. `rustup install nightly-2022-02-02`